# How to get instagram feeds in Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, instagram

I am implementing a blog website using spring boot and Bootstrap, I want to add my instagram feeds in the main page (display the last 6 posted pictures ). My question is how to get the last 6 posted pictures in instagram of a public account ?

Thanks,
Akrem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the instagram api, use the OAuth2 protocol, look at the authentication section and endpoints

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication

If you are building an app that does not have a server component (a purely javascript app, for instance), you will notice that it is impossible to complete step three above to receive your access_token without also having to store the secret on the client. You should never pass or store your client_id secret onto a client. For these situations there is the Implicit Authentication Flow.
Step One: Direct your user to our authorization URL

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token

At this point, we present the user with a login screen and then a confirmation screen where they grant your app’s access to their Instagram data. Note that unlike the explicit flow the response type here is “token”.
Step Two: Receive the access_token via the URL fragment

Once the user has authenticated and then authorized your application, Instagram redirects them to your redirect_uri with the access_token in the url fragment. It will look like this:

http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

Simply grab the access_token off the URL fragment and you’re good to go. If the user chooses not to authorize your application, you’ll receive the same error response as in the explicit flow